# Best practices for autosave forms in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

Many providers are moving towards a paradigm of no-save button and streaming the changes to the backend. Are there any vaadin best practices when using a data binder and forms or input?

So how would one handle partially complete forms, increased database traffic, or triggering a save on defocus or window close etc?

Comment: SO is not the right place for questions like this (opionion based, multiple questions, ...). SO is about concrete programming problems. This is better suited for a forum or alike.

Comment: You should ask this question in the Discord Channel https://discord.com/invite/vaadin

Comment: IMO SO is the completely wrong forum for Vaddin to provide support to their customers, but it was their choice to do so. They shut down their own product forum and now direct their customers to this site for answers. I would expect that I could ask any question of any nature here concerning Vaadin. Concerning Vaadin are there now certain unwritten rules around what type of question should be asked on what forum/discussion board?

Comment: @Franz I strongly doubt, that (paying) customers are supposed to ask here? The rules of SO apply here - it does not matter what written or unwritten rules there are around.  If you had the impression, that here is the best place to ask, then there clearly is a communication problem. But then again, this might be the wrong tree to bark upon. You should make your customers voice be heard at the place, where it can make a difference. It will prevent frustration for all sides.

Comment: Vaadin have a paid Pro level with "community support" and a paid Premium level with "Vaadin support". I am on the Pro package and they direct the Pro members to this forum. Thank you for pointing this out and I hope the Vaadin folk are reading this.

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin has [Binder](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/binding-data/components-binder) utility class for handling data objects to forms. It takes care of the validation, showing validation errors  and guarding not saving unvalidated data. It can operated both in un-buffered and buffered mode.

You can either load and save data using

```
binder.readBean(bean); // populates the form with bean
...
binder.writeBean(bean); // save data from the fields to bean, throws validation exception if not valid
```

Whe you have save button, you usually call `Binder#writeBean` in button's click event. You can alternatively use

```
binder.setBean(bean);
```

When using this method `Binder` syncs data to bean automatically when valid. This is the way to use `Binder` with forms without the save button.

Comment: Thanks Tatu. So using Binder in unbuffered mode will automatically update the bean when the data is valid. How do I best trigger the save to the database? Should I even write the whole bean to the database on every change, or should there be some interim layer handling database updates? If so, what would the design of this layer look like?

Comment: There are couple of options for that. You can for example use binder.addValueChangeListener(..) or binder.setValidationStatusHandler(..) the first one is fired when any bound field value is changed and the second one is fired when values changes between valid / non-valid. E.g. you could use the later one to do save every time values turn valid.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Is the basic design in these "no save buttons" designs to save continuously to the database and add the load there?